# How to implement Laravel's collection `filter` method inside twig?

Tags: templating, collections

How to implement Laravel's collection `filter` method inside twig?

Laravel:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4]);
 
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 2;
});
$filtered->all();
```

How can I do this inside twig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `filter` filter.

```twig
{% set filtered = items|filter(item => item > 2) %}
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#filter